# choose thresholds for 100% sensitivity in glm and lda (wbcd, R)

Tags: r, glm, lda, threshold

I'm working on Wisconsin Breast Cancer Dataset, my aim is to build a model which features a good accuracy and 100% sensitivity. I know that in order to achieve this, I've to work with the thresholds. The problem is that I don't understand how does thresholds work and how can I properly choose them.

I'm studying on the famous Intro to SL (with applications in R) book, but I'm not able to find the explanation about choosing the threshold in chapter 4.

Here is the code I've written so far:

```
df <- subset(df, select = -c(X, id)) # Selecting features
set.seed(4)


# Train and test
nrows <- NROW(df)                        
index <- sample(1:nrows, 0.7 * nrows)  
traindf <- df[index,]                   
testdf <- df[-index,]

glm.fit=glm(diagnosis~., data=traindf ,family=binomial)
glm.probs=predict(glm.fit,testdf,type="response")
glm.pred=rep("B",dim(tested)[1])
glm.pred[glm.probs >.5]="M"
table(glm.pred, testdf[,1])
```

Now, this gives me

```
glm.pred   B   M
       B 108   3
       M   4  56
```

What I want is to put 0 in the top right of the table, but changing the thresholds doesn't work.

How can I fix the problem?

The same is with the lad function (which I avoid to write here).

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried changing the value of `0.5` in this line: `glm.pred[glm.probs >.5]="M"`?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I need in order to change the threshold. My question is how do I decide the value in order to get 100% sensitivity

Comment: @FedericoSparapan this question is more of a statexchange question. In general to decide the threshold you predict on the training data then try to optimize based on some criteria of interest (e.g. select threshold based on accuracy, sensitivity, specificity, etc) and then use that threshold on your predicted data.